# How to control zoom in and zoom out in shiny dashboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, r, shiny

When I zoom in or zoom out the shiny dashboard page (in chrome), I would like to zoom in or zoom out the area around the mouse rather than relatively zoom in or zoom out the entire page.

**This is the original page**
[image]

**This is what "zoom" is doing now**
[image]

**This is what I want the "zoom" to do**
[image]

Please see the minimal reproducible example below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    
    # css solution
    tags$style(""),
    
    # javascript / jquery solution
    tags$script("")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

### **Rather than what mentioned above, I will also accept the answer that dynamically adjust the page so it looks like "zoom" is disabled.**

Comment: Different browsers zoom differently. Some just make text larger, others crop, and others still increase the size of everything and even apply media queries.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks for you comment, I only need it working with chrome, I will highlight the text in description .

Comment: Please don't make things chrome only.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks for you comment, I have removed the highlight.

Comment: @evolutionxbox my issue is that I don't know how to "corp" a section in the page and makes it look like zoom in and zoom out, can you please provide some insights or references, thanks!

Comment: What I mean is that I don't think it's something that can be controlled

Comment: @evolutionxbox is it possible to change the width and the height of a web page dynamically, so it looks like zoom is disabled?

Comment: I don't know sadly.